# cannot enter my password when login to the tty

Tags: ssh, login, password, tty

My PC machine is in ubuntu 16.04.

I want to login the tty, However ,when I input my username and press the 'enter' button , I can't input my password straight after that.It seems that two 'enter's were input automatically somehow .

I could login tty normally before.The only thing I did meanwhile was configuring ssh on the PC machine for my laptop to access it .

[image: can't input password]